# How to sync repositories between 2 PCs?

Tags: java, github, repository, git-push, git-clone

I'm new to github and I've just learned how to push changes. **I have a school and home pc**, and I often switch between the two depending on where I'm at. I first made my repository on the school pc, and I've cloned it once at home. I then made some few new files to test out the push and commit stuff using my home pc.

So now I have a home pc synced with my online github repository. My question is, when I go to school and use my school pc, how would I sync the school pc local repository to my online repository? Should I clone it (similar with what I did for the home pc)? or is there another way to sync it? I was thinking that maybe cloning it again and again every time I switch PCs would be too redundant.

Comment: pull changes from GitHub first thing, push to GitHub last thing

Comment: [`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull). Also [hang this in your computer room at school (`repository-images.githubusercontent.com`)](https://repository-images.githubusercontent.com/43623432/e3756280-e50c-11e9-877f-24272543fd9c)

Comment: ^ this. Technically recloning would work, it's just inefficient. Pull can download just the delta (what has changed), while clone will download the entire repo. There may also be build artifacts in your local version that you'd prefer not to wipe out every time you swap.